# Hooking up IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation and Reference Tokens with ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, bearer-token

I am try to build out an **Angular 6** application backed by a **ASP.NET Web API** back end. The application authenticates users against a separate **Identity Server 4** that federates Azure AD ultimately returning a **Bearer** reference token.

From a login and then authenticate (the token) perspective, everything is working. The user access the site, gets redirected to Azure AD, logs in, and gets redirected back to the Angular 6 app. For the API calls, the token is injected into the header and the ASP.NET Core authentication middleware validates the token and returns the data.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => {
        options.Authority = AuthClient.SsoBaseUrl;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ApiName = AuthClient.SsoClientName;
        options.ApiSecret = AuthClient.SsoClientSecret;
    });
```

My problem is that I am trying to incorporate ASP.NET Core Identity and I am unsure of where/how to tie the `claims principal` returned via `AddIdentityServerAuthentication`.

In a previous version (ASP.NET Framework 4.7) of this application, we used `Ws-Federation` which redirected back to `ExternalCallbackLogin()` in `AccountController` which executed the usual `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` and then `SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync()` and then (**if required**) `AppUserManager.CreateAsync()` and `AppUserManager.AddLoginAsync()`.

This code basically checked the `[AspNetUserLogins]` table for the provider specific key (from the claims) to map to a user in the `[AspNetUsers]` table.

With the change to `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` I cannot figure out where to put this logic. Since I am using **reference tokens** it does not look like the `JwtBearerEvents` (specifically the `OnTokenValidated` event) is not being raised. In fact, it does **not** look like there **are** any `Introspection` events...??

I am tried testing the logic in a test endpoint that called the above "Manager" methods (technically it was the updated for `ASP.NET Core Identity` equivalent methods) but that is not working either.

For example, the very first call to `SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running into this same issue.  The switch to reference tokens has worked out great but now we're trying to add claims to validated identity and unable to find a solution without the OnTokenValidated event.

Comment: Use OAuth2IntrospectionEvents